# Power On But No Power

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

I have a GE 20amp Breaker that feeds my Dining room and outdoor power for Linai.  Breaker off, no power going out, breaker on power at the panel.  No power in aforementioned area.   GFI outside, replaced with new, still no power.

What are the possibilities?  Ground or short somewhere?  But why wouldn't that trip the breaker? From what I can tell, this 20 amp breaker also feeds the Microwave. I have unplugged everything, reset the breaker many times, still no power.  Removed cover of main panel and tested breaker with my voltage tester...

Comment: _>>also feeds the Microwave_  Why do you say that?  Does microwave work?  Also, are you SURE you have the correct breaker? Maybe another one is tripped (they can be hard to detect visually)

Comment: It was my understanding that microwaves should be on their own 20amp.  I have voltage testers and while it worked yesterday that one time, I was able to verify correct breaker.

Comment: What was strange is I had 120v on the outside GFI when touched to ground, but not to the nuetral (white) and no continuity? @mike65535  Called an electrician before I end up electrocuting myself.

Answer (score 1):

Grounded hot or a short will trip the breaker. But a loose wire will not.

With the breaker off, check every receptacle in the circuit for a loose connection. If you find backstab connections move them to screws. Start with receptacle nearest the breaker, though sometimes the wiring is not done in the most obvious /logical path.